# Different Encodings / Reponses from Google Geocoding-API

Tags: java, grails, character-encoding, geocoding

I'm writing tests for my Grails-Application and I found a "bug" in my application - at least I think its my application.

My request looks like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Karlsruhe+76131+Tullastraße+17&sensor=false
```

And the response contains my state / province (I don't know the exact translation - I'm from Germany and it's divided into 16 smaller "states" - called "Bundesland")

My state is called "Baden-Württemberg" and thats in the response from the browser.

In my application I'm using an URL and a BufferedReader (with an InputStreamReader) to get the response.

I'm trying to assert, that the response from the browser is equal to the response I get from the URL-Connection in my code.

But - here comes the question/ problem - they differ. And the only difference I found was in the name of my state.

As mentioned before the response I got from the browser contains "Baden-Württemberg", but the response I get through my code contains only "Baden-Wurttemberg" - the *ü* is switched with a regular *u*

Here's my code:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection()

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.content, "UTF-8" ))
StringBuffer connectionResponse = new StringBuffer()

while (br.ready()) {
    connectionResponse.append(br.readLine())
}
br.close()
return connectionResponse.toString()
```

My search led me to the option of passing a charset to the InputStreamReader - as I expect it's UTF-8 I use this charset, but it's not solving this bug.

Im just confused why this is possible.

Where should I look ? I'm not that experienced so I'm rather clueless

Edit:
I tested some more and if I search with a street containing an umlaut ("Bärenweg" or "Baerenweg" would be an example), both responses (code and browser) contain the correct value: Bärenweg. It seems only the state is affected by this.

Should I contact google right away? With this new test I'm not really sure if I can do something about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved. 
I asked a colleague of mine and he suggested, that the only reasonable cause could be different Request-Headers.

The only way I could think of right away was to do it with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). So i downloaded and installed it (WinPCab installed with it) and startet it after the installation.

First I triggered both requests by pressing F5 in Firefox and running my tests in Grails

Then I added the filter "http.response" (meaning all responses from HTTP request should be visible).
The Response-Headers were almost equal and it didn't occur any obvious mistake.

Then I filtered for "http.request" to compare the headers sent to the google-api and there was a bit more off, then in the response.

First I compared the Accept-Property and set the property in my code to the value from the Browser-Response (the one, which works fine). 
Didn't solve the problem.

So next property: Accept-Language.

In the Request-header from the code this property wasn't there at all, so I copied it from the Browser-Request-header and kazaam: it works!

```
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
```

to set this property on the connection add the following code:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
```

TL;DR / Long story short

set the language-property in the request-header and google knows what language you expect the response to be in.

Answer (score 0):

The query string of the URL should be URL-encoded so `ß` is turned into an escape sequence. `URLEncoder.encode("?...", "UTF-8")`.

Comment: that doesn't matter in case of the google api, as it always returns the correct values. Nevertheless I fixed it - look at my response